# What is wrong with this connection string?

Tags: asp.net, mysql, connection-string

Hai guys,

I use the following connection string

```
<add name="connectionString" connectionString="server=localhost;user id=root; password=; database=lms; pooling=false;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
```

It gives me the error `There is no 'lms'@'%' registered`.

My database server is localhost and the user account doesn't have a password..

Comment: user id=root.  Are you sure space is allowed between user id, isn't it userid?

Comment: What driver are you using to connect to MySQL - OLE or ODBC? `user id=` is OLE syntax; `uid=` or `USER=` is ODBC: http://www.webcheatsheet.com/ASP/mysql_connection_strings.php

Comment: What happens when you run `mysql --user=root lms`?  If that works, what is returned when you execute `SELECT User, Host FROM mysql.user;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working connection string for MySql:

```
server=localhost;user id=root;password=xxx;database=xxx;pooling=false
```

Can you connect from the command line (using "mysql")?

Is mysql by any chance bound to a different IP other than localhost (in my.ini)?

If you don't have a password, have you tried leaving off `password=`?

If that doesn't work, you may have to add a password....

Answer (score 0):

F0r MySql, should be something like:

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be something like:

```
<add name="ConnString" connectionString="Database=lmz;Data Source=localhost;User Id=root;Password=;CHARSET=utf8;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
```

Also check that the user has permissions to the database.